# What kind of data structure is a monad?

Tags: haskell, data-structures, compilation, monads, functor

I have a half-competent understanding of what a monad is (a parameterized type that provides a context for useful computation building), why it exists (so you can do things that require context, like IO), how to use it (bind returned variables with `>>=`), and a very rough understanding of where it fits in in category theory (a category that guarantees homogeneity of contexts of functions)**.

What, however, is a monad in terms of the underlying data structure?  Since it is related to an applicative functor (which seems like a list), my guess is that GHC takes the monad's contents and puts them into a linked list of some sort, and passes them around throughout the computation.

What is really going on underneath the hood?

** feel free to correct any of this if you know better.

Comment: "contents" does not necessarily imply a box, it can be a transmission carrying a signal. Not just burritos, rum-soaked cakes are monads too. and holograms.

Comment: @WillNess, where do you live and can you teach me to make rum-soaked cakes?

Answer (score 10):

Monad is not a data structure — it's a property.

You can define a class of data types that have some default values (like `[]` for lists, `0` for `Int`, `False` for `Bool` and so on). Let's call this class `Defaultable`. Then you postulate that the default integer is `0` and thus prove that the type of integers is `Defaultable`. `Bool` is `Defaultable` in the same way.

Another example is the `ToStringable` class (`Show` in Haskell): A type is `ToStringable` if there is a function from it to `String`. `Int` and `Bool` are `ToStringable`, because you can write functions

```
intToString  :: Int  -> String
boolToString :: Bool -> String
```

(and lists of type `[a]` are meaningfully `ToStringable` if `a` is `ToStringable`)

Likewise, the type of lists is a monad: you can define two operations (that obey certain laws) `return` and `(>>=)` and thus prove that the type of lists forms a monad. And that is: if you can define two operations

```
return :: a -> m a
(>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

for some concrete `m`, then this `m` is a monad. So `Monad` is a class and classes very much remind interfaces in OOP.

Internally it's just [dictionaries passing](https://www.schoolofhaskell.com/user/jfischoff/instances-and-dictionaries).

Answer (score 8):

A monad may or may not be a data structure. To get some data-structural intuition into monads, you should definitely read Dan Piponi's blog post [Monads are Trees with Grafting](http://blog.sigfpe.com/2010/01/monads-are-trees-with-grafting.html?m=1).

The most boring data structural monad is the free monad over a functor,

```
data Free f a = Pure a
              | Free (f (Free a))

instance Functor f => Monad (Free f) where ...
```

Since you mention lists, you should probably look into the operational monad and perhaps the codensity monad.